# How to create a remote database for an android app?

Tags: android, database, web-services

I am trying to create a RESTful web service for an android application. I would like to first create a users table that will store the users information such as username, password, email etc. I have read some links of this but I am unsure if proper programming practice. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What Web language you would like to use?

Comment: Which one would you recommend, I looked around and some people say JSON or XML . Perhaps JSON. @ZahidRasheed

Comment: Okay. Like phpmyadmin? How can I create a database to store the information of the users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following elements to start with your app

Firstly: A database server where you will create a database and tables, one if those tables would have users and their passwords.
Secondly: A webservice that will recieve your app requests, query the database and return response to your app
Lastly your app

I would recomend to start reading about firebase, it is a Google product, fast and easy to integrate with mobile apps.

You can also use MySql database and php servers

For me I am using MS SQL Server with ASP.net web services

Good luck

Comment: Thank you! This is the type of answer I was looking for. Taking a look at firebase it seems to be more of an analytic tool. May you explain how I can use this ?

Comment: Look at this link, it will give you some idea. https://youtu.be/xAsvwy1-oxE

Comment: Thank you for this link. I am already beginning to see how firebase is so useful. I am not finished with the video but, would I be able to use for example firebase as a database server and ASP.net for the web services?

Comment: Firebase is equiped with tools that can avoid the integration with other 'third parties' products. Give one hour of your time to know more about firebase and then decide based on your app idea and functions

Answer (score 1):

You need to use at least one server side language to write down your web services. I would recommend PHP. 
I would recommend you using SLIM Framework for that. This can help you easily create Routes and pretty easy to maintain. 
Ref: http://slimframework.com/docs/tutorial/first-app.html

Comment: so SLIM is used to create the database?

Comment: SLIM is PHP Framework. You have no basic concepts of Server side languages and API. I would recommend you to first read this to know what is a RESTFUL API http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide an article on creating a restful api with java perhaps?

Comment: Try this: https://www.boxuk.com/insight/blog-posts/creating-rest-api-quickly-using-pure-java